# Content security policy not coming on 301 http-to-https redirect

Tags: apache, aem, content-security-policy, dispatcher, http-redirect

I am using dispatcher-cnfig for **http** to **https** redirect for my AEM site. But I don't see "Content security policy" coming on the 301 redirect. And it comes fine from the next 200 call on-wards where the site is now on 'https'.

Any suggestion to get the Content-security-policy called on 301-redirect call as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any content in a 301 redirect to enforce a security policy on?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find the solution. @ronnyfm

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug, example like it is www.google.com  and now it is getting redirected to www.google.com/newUrl . So, content is serving from new url. Is this what you were asking ?

Comment: A redirect should be headers only, there is no content and no need for a content security policy. Framework may omit it if it doesn't make sense to send. Final 200 has content and it makes sense to include it.

Comment: I found that the redirect [R=301,L] happens and because of that the Header is not adding after the redirect. Any idea how to get policy added before that ? what rule tweaks do I need to perform?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the content-security-policy working on 301 redirect.

Earlier the content-security Header was under `<Directory />`and I moved it under `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` . This worked for me.